# mvn clean fails with error "can not delete class"

Tags: java, maven, class, command, jobs

```sh
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) on project c$$e: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /a$$ce/target/classes/.nfs000000000006e23600000003
```

Answer (score 1):

If **mvn clean** is failing to delete target, Go to the location of target folder in File explorer and delete target manually